# Why is getting the bare minimum set up to get started with using LaTeX such a heavy process?

Tags: installing, windows

I want to make notes on math lectures using LaTeX (inspired by [this blog post](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/)) and I've not really used the tech before. What I've done before is using Google Docs and its insert equation functionality, and more recently I also discovered that using a LaTeX plugin I can render matrices as images to my document too (which was not supported by Google Docs' equations).

I might later move on to Linux and thereafter would be able to follow the linked blog post but for now I have to figure out a way to accomplish what I want on a Windows system.

So, if I've understood the fundamentals right all I need and want is any text editor that supports snippets for fast typing (like Sublime Text 3 that I'm familiar with) and some sort of compiler that would turn my source code into a PDF. That doesn't sound very complex. However, installing TeX Live is a really extremely long process for some reason which made me doubt whether I'm even doing the right thing or am I perhaps installing something completely unnecessary too? I just want to grasp what would be the very minimum required to get to compile documents from LaTeX markup to understand the tech.

Comment: If online services are an option, you could look at overleaf.com.

Comment: Yes, TeX Live default install more that you will need,  but is a more extremely long process deal with problems because  this or that is still was not  installed. MikTeX (usual Windows alternative to TeX Live) make a basic install and then install packages only if required ... supposedly, but in practice sometimes some package is not installed for some reason, and then you will need (a) find out the problem and (b) a manual install/update of that  package-s . Maybe is only a trivial problem,  but who barely understands what he is doing will be not happy with these problems.

Comment: On the other hand, Linux distro usually have their own `texlive` packages that allow an partial install as with any other program, and that can be completed easily when you want.  The only problem with this alternative is that it can a bit outdated version, but in 99% of cases that will not matter at al.

Comment: On the other hand [TinyTeX](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) is a lightweight, cross-platform, portable, and easy-to-maintain LaTeX distribution based on TeX Live. This could be a interesting option if you already know RStudio.

Comment: these days the minimum requiremt is to install nothing and use an online tex installation such as overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/  most of the regulars here install a full texlive, which is a lot of software but for most people, most of the time it is better to install the lot than try to install a subset and fight with the complex dependencies between the various parts.